Enable Microsoft Defender For Cloud at resource level for App Services
I want to enable Defender for Cloud for a subset of resources in an Azure subscription. I already enabled it for some VMs as mentioned in this blog
I need to enable this for some of the app services in this subscription. this is what I tried so far,
$url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$appServiceName/providers/Microsoft.Security/pricings/AppServices?api-version=2024-01-01"

$accessToken = (Get-AzAccessToken).Token
    $headers = @{
        "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken"
        "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
    }
$body = @{
location   = $location
properties = @{
    pricingTier = "Standard"
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json


Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $url -Body $body -Headers $headers

This is the error I get:

Invoke-RestMethod :
{"error":{"code":"InvalidUrlConfiguration","message":"The plan name
'AppServices' is not supported for resource  level pricing."}}

When I run the following command I get a null value output:
https://management.azure.com/{scopeId}/providers/Microsoft.Security/pricings?api-version=2024-01-01
output:
{
  "value": []
}

Is there a way (GUI, REST API or CLI) I can enable defender for cloud for App services without enabling it at the subscription level?

As mentioned in this MS Document, only 'VirtualMachines, VMSS and ARC Machines' are supported to enable Microsoft Defender for Cloud at resource level. To enable Microsoft Defender for Cloud in App Service, you can do it only at subscription level.

Yes, but it allows to enable defender for cloud for storage accounts at the resource level using the Azure portal. Is there a way to enable this in any other way? (Portal, CLI etc.)

Yes, but for App Service resource type, you must enable at subscription level only. There is no other way. Check this MS Document too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/tutorial-enable-app-service-plan#prerequisites

Initially, I too got same error when I tried to enable Microsoft Defender for Cloud at resource level for App Services with below script:
$url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$appServiceName/providers/Microsoft.Security/pricings/AppServices?api-version=2024-01-01"

$accessToken = (Get-AzAccessToken).Token
    $headers = @{
        "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken"
        "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
    }
$body = @{
location   = $location
properties = @{
    pricingTier = "Standard"
    }
} | ConvertTo-Json

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $url -Body $body -Headers $headers

Response:

As I mentioned in comments, there is no way to enable Microsoft Defender for Cloud at resource level for App Services as of now.
For App Services, the only way is to enable Microsoft Defender for Cloud at subscription level.  Refer this MS Doc stating the same:

You must enable Microsoft Defender for Cloud on your Azure subscription. You must have a supported App Service plan associated with dedicated machines.

You can make use of below CLI command to enable Microsoft Defender for Cloud for App Services at subscription level:
az security pricing create -n AppServices --tier standard

Response:

You can confirm whether Microsoft Defender for Cloud for App Services is enabled or not at subscription level by checking this tab in Azure Portal GUI:

